# Will this network layout work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, switch

I need to set up a network in my office so I can have a company come and install software for me. They are going to setup my front office computer so I can perform normal tasks on it and it will function as an SQL server. But I need to have my other PCs connected to. I made two possible network maps and I am looking for any input or advice before I move forward. Any help is appreciated.

Map 1

`ISP-->Modem-->Network Switch-->WiFi Router & All PCs(Including SQL Server)`

Map 2

`ISP-->Modem-->WiFi Router-->SQL Server PC-->Network Switch-->All other PCs`

There are 6 Desktops total, and two WiFi laptops. Also, can the PC running the SQL Server operate with a wireless connection?

Comment: I would suggest against running the SQL server on a wifi connection, especially if it is heavily used. You could probably get away with that though if it not used frequently or heavily.

Answer (score 0):

Map 1 works (almost)

Map 2 works against you because the diagram suggests you will be routing traffic through your SQL Server PC. This is ill advised as it complicates your network topography without adding any gain whatsoever (prove me wrong?).

There is one minor thing you want to change to Map 1.

ISP > Modem > Router > Switch > Server and other PCs

Comment: putting the network switch, which just enables more ports on the network BEFORE the router?  The router gets the connection, and handles DHCP to all the connected machines.  Wouldn't putting the switch AFTER the router expand the available number of ports?  Putting it before means that multiple computers could connect directly to the modem, but the modem doesn't route the connection to multiple machines... only one.  So, shouldn't it be modem - router - switch - all computers?

Comment: @Bon Gart I'm editing my post (you probably posted this while I have been editing it)

Comment: @Ben I have updated my post.

Comment: Thank you both, this has helped me greatly, I'm going to re-plan the network as you described and get it started! Thanks again.

Comment: @Ben mind upvoting please?

Comment: Don't be so demanding — this sounds quite rude. New users can't even upvote.

Comment: @BonGart Actually in a home office environment a router wouldnt be used at all. The reason people say router is because the wireless router has a small switch in it that moves packets between the switch ports and the wireless network. Unfortunately this is a HUGE miss conception of what a real router does. Also it sounds like everyone here is getting confused about router and switch terminology. Routers simply expand the number of networks you can have by routing the packets, they do not expand ports. A switch expands the amount of devices that can connect.

Comment: @onxx the OP did not say whether or not the SQL server would be handling DHCP or not, which makes a difference as to where it would be placed in the order of things... namely if it had two ethernet cards, one connected to the modem, and the other connected to the switch.  In such a case, the "router" would only be necessary to allow for wireless connections.  However, if the SQL server was only there to act as the central database to be connected to, and otherwise not as a domain server, the router should be necessary to pass out IP addresses to all the connected computers, no?

Comment: @BonGart I highly doubt that the SQL box would be used in that design because if it was ben would not be asking for network advice as you would have to create static routes for the other PCs to connect to the web.I think that its an oversight you might have made on who or where DHCP is coming from. Again, it doesn't have to be router that passes it out. As long as its a managed network device, pretty much these days everything is. The wifi router, will have a slim linux distro thats acting as a DHCP server; Standard in all these types of devices...

Answer (score 0):

One important factor that you have over looked is the use of a firewall. If any of this data is going to be sensitive you should be first thinking about protection, especially when adding a SQL box to the mix.

I would try instead **Map3** ISP-->Modem-->Firewall -->Network Switch-->SQL Server PC-->All wired PCs| WiFi Router (Connected to Network switch)--> wireless PCs

On a different note have you thought about getting a modem/wifi router and then just adding an additional switch to that? Most wifi/modem routers will come with an onboard 4 port switch and they are extremely easy to setup.

Comment: Thank you everybody for all of your comments and help. I cannot provide a lot of information on the SQL server, as I will not be setting it up. The company for the software I purchased will be doing that, and they simply told me I need to have the entire network established before they come. They also told me it would be helpful if I setup the workgroup and file sharing as well. Based on that, I do not think static IPs are going to be used.

Comment: Looking at your Map 3 design I have a quick question, just to make sure, every PC and the WiFi router connect to the switch correct? Also, in considering a firewall, would something like the D-Link DIR-130 VPN Firewall 8 with 8-Port 10/100Mbps Switch work as both the switch and firewall? If so, would it conflict with the WiFi router? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Ben Yes, however if you are hosting a website from home there maybe some design issues with the loop back address 127.0.0.1.